# Good books on distributed systems

Tags: distributed-system, paxos

Is there a really good book that covers in depth: two phase commit, paxos as well as limitations in achieving consistency, availability, partition tolerance.

Browsing Amazon it is amazing to see the number of distributed systems books that don't even cover paxos.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399099/good-books-on-distributed-computing-distributed-architecutre - possible duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The thing with the Paxos algorithm is that it's fairly recent (published as a journal article in 1998 according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paxos_(computer_science)) and classic books like [Readings in Database Systems](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558605231) or [Transaction Processing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558601902) cover the other topics you care about, but actually pre-date Paxos!